# Using the value of a PHP variable to modify the current time in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page which, among other things, assigns a value to the `$deviance` variable.  The value of this variable is always an integer, generally between 0 and 45.

I then need javascript to use the `$deviance` value to be added as minutes to current time as determined by javascript.

For example, if `$deviance = 10`, then a current time of `13:55:10` becomes `14:05:10`, so that these values result:

- `var hour = 14`
- `var minute = 5`
- `var second = 10`

In PHP, I calculate the value of `$deviance` thusly:

```
$a = new DateTime("$str_deviation");
$b = new DateTime('12:00');

$deviant = $a->diff($b);

$deviance = ( ( $deviant->format('%H') * 60 ) + ( $deviant->format('%i') ) );
```

Then, I use the PHP variable in javascript:

```
var deviation=<?php echo json_encode($deviance); ?>;

var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes( now.getMinutes() + deviation);
document.write( now );

var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
```

Any help in finding my error will be greatly appreciated!

[Using: Standard LAMP config on Debian 11 server]

Comment: Why you encode in json format when you assign php value to js variable?

Comment: @Eriks what error you got? can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: @LelioFaieta is right.  <?php echo $deviance; ?>  should mean in javascript your variable deviation is what you want.

Comment: I used JSON originally out of habit to avoid characters that would break the javascript (which I don't need to do here since all values will be integers).  After going to the straight variable, it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `json_encode`.

You can solve the problem by changing

```js
var deviation=<?php echo json_encode($deviance); ?>;
```

to

```js
var deviation=<?php echo $deviance; ?>;
```

*Thank you to @Lelio and @dave!*